# Let $R$ be the triangle with vertices in $(0,0)$, $(0,1)$, $(1,0)$. Find: $\iint_R \exp((y-x)/( y+x))\, dx\,dy.$

Tags: calculus, integration, substitution

I have a problem with this:

Let $R$ be the triangle with vertices in $(0,0)$, $(0,1)$, $(1,0)$.

Find:
$$\iint_R \exp\left({y-x\over y+x}\right)\, dx\,dy.$$
I tried to use the substitution $u=y+x$ and $v=y-x$, getting  Jacobian determinant $\mathbf J={1\over 2}$, but I don't know how to find the the new integration limits.

Comment: What were your limits back when you had $x$ and $y?$

Comment: Do you know how to show that $0\le x+y\le 1 \text{ ?} \qquad$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/331236/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2466698/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3141532/321264

Answer (score 1, accepted):

prior to your change of coordinates your limits were 
$x = 0, y = 0, x+y = 1$

If $u = x+y, v = x-y$

$x = \frac 12 u + \frac 12 v\\
y = \frac 12 u - \frac 12 v$

and substitute

$u = v\\
u = -v\\
u = 1$

Answer (score 0):

Your initial area of integration is given by

$$R = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : 0 \le x \le 1, 0 \le y \le 1-x\}$$

Let $u = y+x$, $v = y-x$. We have

$$ 0 \le y+x \le 1 \implies u \in [0,1]$$
$$ \left|v\right| = \left|y-x\right| \le |y| + |x| = y+x = u \implies v \in [-u,u]$$

so the new area of integration is 
$$S = \{(u,v) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : 0 \le u \le 1, -u \le v \le u\}$$

Therefore, your integral is

\begin{align}
\iint_R \exp \left(\frac{y-x}{y+x}\right)\,dx\,dy &= \frac12\iint_{S} \exp\left(\frac{v}{u}\right)\,du\,dv \\
&=\frac12 \int_0^1 \int_{-u}^u \exp\left(\frac{v}{u}\right)\,dv\,du\\
&= \frac12 \int_0^1 u\left(e - \frac1e\right)\,du\\
&= \frac14 \left(e - \frac1e\right)\\
&= \frac{e^2-1}{4e}
\end{align}

Comment: The limits for $u$ are fine, but the limits for $v$ should be $-u$ and $u$ instead of $-1$ and $1$. Note that the transformation can be decomposed into a reflection, a rotation and a scaling, so the resulting region should still be a triangle, not a rectangle (see my answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2823732/solving-integral-by-substitution/2824947#2824947) question for details). The correct value of the integral, $\frac{\mathrm{e}^2 - 1}{4 \mathrm{e}}$, is found with these limits.

Comment: @ComplexYetTrivial You are right about the limits for $v$, thanks for the correction. But are you sure about the final result? Could you check my calculation here?

Comment: There is a mistake in the second step: $\mathrm{e}^{v/u} \neq \mathrm{e}^v \mathrm{e}^{-u}$.

Comment: @ComplexYetTrivial True, thanks. I have no idea how to evaluate this integral, though.

Comment: The exponent should be $\frac{y-x}{y+x} = \frac{v}{u}$. Then the resulting integral is nice.

Comment: @ComplexYetTrivial Thanks a lot, I finally got the correct result.